# I can't define a path in python. The backslash is seen as an continuation character

Tags: python, path

I have an error in my code when i use a path. I'm trying to build in a bit of code to check if a file exists. In the previous exercises in my tutorial I could place the path within quotation marks but this path is not an argument to a function and won't accept this.

This is my code:

```
if os.C:\Users\\Casper\Desktop\headfirstpython\chapter 3.exits('sketch.txt')
data = open('sketch.txt')
for each_line in data:
    try:
        (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':', 1)
        print(role, end='')
        print(' said: ', end='')
        print(line_spoken, end='')
    except:
        pass

data.close()
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could tell me what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Is that *really* the first line of your code?!

Comment: Yes sir. Do you wan't to tell me why this is shocking you?

Comment: mhlester has covered that well in their answer; it is sufficiently far from valid syntax that I assumed you'd made an error in copying it across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong on a few levels:

```
if os.C:\Users\\Casper\Desktop\headfirstpython\chapter 3.exits('sketch.txt')
```

You need to use:

```
if os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\headfirstpython\chapter 3\sketch.txt'):
```

I changed three things:

1. it's `os.path.exists(path)`. The path isn't a valid function name. It's a string, passed as an argument.
2. The backslashes need to be handled in one of three ways:

   - Escaped as *two* backslashes, which means one literal baclshash.
   - Use a forward slash (`/`). This does work even on Windows.
   - With `r'string'` notation, where the `r` tells Python to interpret it literally, without any characters escaped.
3. You need to end your `if` statements with a colon (`:`). Further, you'll need to indent the code under it so Python knows what precisely to execute in the case the `if` is True.

As noted in the comments, be sure you've added `import os` to the top as well, or `os` will be undefined!

Comment: You could also do `os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\headfirstpython\chapter 3\sketch.txt')` so that you don't have to escape your slashes

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel really stupid now. I really appreciate the quick response to such an obvious error!!

Comment: Probably needs `import os` at the top too.